# Regex in Python: find three floating point numbers before "&"

Tags: python, regex

I'm pretty inexperienced with Regex and can't generate an approach with Regex in Python that works regardless of variations in strings read into Python. I have the following strings, where word is any string in characters:

;word 1

word ID 1,-10.2268800735474,11.54,1 &,

word ID 1 -10.2268800735474,11.54,1 &,

word ID 1 -10.2268800735474,11.54,1 &

word word 1 -2,11,1 &

word word 1 35.21844,35.94909,0.19633 34.84798,36.01114,-0.33727 34.60227,36.46051,0.18769 &

What I'd like to extract is:

1. The three floating point numbers before "&" when the line ends with "&" into a list.
2. When a line DOES NOT end with "&" AND does not start with ";", get the three floating point numbers before the line ends.

To clarify, the "&" indicates the line in the text file being read into other software is a continuation of the previous line. When it encounters a line that does not end with "&" OR has a blank line after a line that ends with "&", it starts a new process. Any gurus that can help?

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your work and an expected output! You already provide a lot of info, which is good, but we need a little more. Take a look at [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), to get an idea...

Comment: Questions that ask ["Give me a regex that does X"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285733) with no attempt are off topic on Stack Overflow. Use http://www.regex101.com or similar ressources to come up with one. If you need regex training use https://regexcrossword.com  to learn regex.

Comment: Thanks Pat, along with learning VB, Python and a dedicated scripting language I was hoping for a little help without having to learn another syntax. Regardless, back to the drawing board it is.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I'll use the following for now until I have the time to properly implement Regex:

([-+]?[0-9]*.?[0-9]+).([-+]?[0-9]*.?[0-9]+).([-+]?[0-9]*.?[0-9]+).(?=&)